# how can i get value from view without use ids?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 7 outcome view in my XML file and I want to control them (get value form them) without declare on each view separately and I want to do a loop (for loop) that over on each view and store the value in array, so anyone can help me with a solution for that problem that I have? 
Thanks in advance for your help.
here is my XML code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:id="@+id/viewLoto1"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.loto.ViewLoto>

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:id="@+id/viewLoto2"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.loto.ViewLoto>

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:id="@+id/viewLoto3"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.loto.ViewLoto>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:id="@+id/viewLoto4"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.loto.ViewLoto>

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:id="@+id/viewLoto5"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.loto.ViewLoto>

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:id="@+id/viewLoto6"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.loto.ViewLoto>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:id="@+id/viewLoto7"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </com.example.loto.ViewLoto>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="The result will be here!" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDraw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Draw numbers" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and java code:

```
package com.example.loto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class ActivityLoto extends Activity
{
   class Layout 
   {
       public Layout()
       {
           txtResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
           btnDraw = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDraw);
       }

       TextView txtResult;
       Button btnDraw;
   }

   int[] views = new int[7];

   class Events
   {
       public Events()
       {
            l.btnDraw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    int[] numbers = new int[7];
                    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)//I stuck here 
                    {
                         int curent =i+1;
                         ViewLoto viewLoto = (ViewLoto)findViewById(R.id.viewLoto+curent);
                         numbers[i] = viewLoto.getValue();
                     }
                }
            });
       }
   }

   Layout l;
   Events e;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loto);

        l = new Layout();
        e = new Events();
   }

}
```

Comment: where do you face issue here? As per your layout there is no use of using 3 `LinearLayout` . Consider using `ListView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through specific View's children like this:

```
List<Integer> lotoValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
for(int i=0; i<layout.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    ViewLoto nextChild = (ViewLoto) layout.getChildAt(i);
    lotoValues.add((Integer)nextChild.getText());
}
```

EDIT:

The above code will loop through a layout's children and their `getText` results to an array lotoValues. Note that your custom views should have a method getText to return the text of the view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.example.loto.ViewLoto
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can explain more about the code that you write?

Comment: thank you for the explain ,but Log demand a String value and i need to get a int ,can I use the nextChild.getText without the Log?and what the purpose of the ViewGroup here?

Comment: As long as the getText returns appropriate value, of course you can. Updated. And the ViewGroup is the layout, which children will be looped.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1:

if your goal is to avoid from create listener for each view, just implement OnClickListener at your class, and on the listener cheack which view is pressed (in that method you need to declare id for each

solution 2:

create your views dynamically and add them to your layout:

```
View views = new View[7];
for(int i=0;i<views.length;i++){
    view[i] = new ViewLoto(); // your custom view
}
```

and add each view to your layout by call yourLayout.addView():

```
LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
for(int i=0;i<views.length;i++){

   // here you can set attribute yo your view. for example onClickListener 
   // view[i].setOnClickListener(this);

    yourLayout.addView(views[i]);
}
```

Comment: there is no way to avoid to declare id for each ?

Comment: If you add each view dynamically, you avoid from declare id for each view.

Comment: my goal is when I click on the "draw numbers" button I want that all 7 custom views value will store in array that I can do use that infrmation to make a dicision what print on TextView so i dont want that the user need to click on each view but just on the "draw numbers" button

Comment: @user15337 exactly what my answer is doing.. I don't see why you would want to create new views when you can define them in the xml. And you only need the id on the layout not the Loto views.

Comment: so you tell me that just over on each layout (and it is like over on array)?